# React hooks updated state not passed to function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to save an api response using react hooksand pass it to a fucntion drawChart. In this code the update state of the object is not being passed to my function. What would be the proper way of passing the updated state of the object to the function drawChart ?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        var obj = JSON.parse(response.data)
        setResponseMonthly(obj);
      })
      .then(response=>{
        drawChart(responseMonthly, 'month')
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },[]);
```

Comment: have you tried await in axios call?

Comment: I guess as it is called with then callbacks no await is needed @aniruddha

Comment: The `await` wouldn't matter since the state update is within the promise chain, nor can you await React state updates anyway, the updated state isn't available until the next render cycle and only the current state enclosed in the hook callback is available. Simplest solution is to just pass the same value state is updated with the function, i.e. `drawChart(obj, 'month')` as pointed out in Davood's solution below.

Answer (score 2):

when you change your state , the component must be rernder to get new state

you can write another `useEffect` like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        var obj = JSON.parse(response.data)
        setResponseMonthly(obj);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },[]);


useEffect(() => {
    if(responseMonthly) drawChart(responseMonthly, 'month')
},[responseMonthly]);
```

or you can call your function like this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        var obj = JSON.parse(response.data)
        setResponseMonthly(obj);
        drawChart(obj, 'month')
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass whatever variable you want to change within the []

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        if (responseMonthly) {
          drawChart(responseMonthly, 'month')
          return 
        }

        axios.get(url)
          .then(response => {
            var obj = JSON.parse(response.data)
            setResponseMonthly(obj);
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
      },[responseMonthly]);
```